# When does the resque worker job stops in ActiveRecord object lifecycle?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, resque

I am giving resque a try, but not sure about resque worker instance's lifecyle. Lets say I have the task set up the following way:

```
class User

  def self.start_job(str)
    Resque.enqueue(Job, str)
  end

end
```

and

```
class Job

  def self.perform(str)
    Message.create(:user => str.split(" ")[0], 
                   :message => str.split(" ")[1])
  end

end
```

After the Message is created, there is after_create hook which calls another long running task:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create (or after_commit) :do_a_ridiculous_long_task

  def do_a_ridiculous_long_task
    do_something
  end

end
```

Does resque worker's lifecycle end right after the message is created, or does it continue until after after_create method in Message model is finished? In other terms, how far does resque worker trail along with the ActiveRecord object's lifecycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that resque worker is not responsible for after_create events it will trigger. Those events will be passed on to rails instance.

Here is the answer: https://github.com/defunkt/resque/issues/483#issuecomment-3396215

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.